# <input> tag inside <div> tags

Tags: javascript, html

I've been learning Javascript for a while now and am making a cookie clicker style game with JS and HTML, however I haven't learned much in the way of HTML and I'm still kinda confuzzeled by div tags. I have tried to split the web page into columns using the div tag, That worked but when I put and  tag in there it didnt show up. Am i being silly?

Source below:

```
<div id="JS" style="float:left; margin:0; width:33%;" align="center">

    <input onclick='addKittens()' type="image" src="kitten.jpg" alt="Add Kittens :)" width="96" height="96">T
</div>


<div id="KPSDiv" style="float:left; margin:0;width:33%;" align="center">


</div>

<div id="CrazyCatLadyDiv" style="float:left; margin:0;width:33%" align="center">


</div>
```

Comment: Not being silly. Did you try removing the style attributes from your div's to make sure they were not overlapping one another?

Comment: The input type is an image??? Why not just an img tag?

Comment: @Jason I don't have any style for the columns or the input, so I doubt they could be overlapping.

Comment: @dcodesmith I chose an input because I needed it to work with javascript hence the onClick attribute. If an img tag can do onClick then I may use that :P

Comment: a click event can be attached to an img tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything in web design is a box/square/rectangle.  DIV's are no different.

The DIV tag is just a container to put other things into; e.g. an INPUT field.

build out a web page and is your css try this:

```
* { border: 1px solid red; }
```

I moved your code into a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jJb77/1/) and had no issue.

Comment: Where the old lady is, is where a different picture should be

Comment: http://prntscr.com/2k5y8m I just turned the other image into a comment to make this easier to see.

Comment: You have three distinct columns.  What are you not accomplishing which you desire to?  Also see [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/all-is-a-box.jpg)

Comment: There should be and image in the left column. but its not there.

Comment: Never mind. I started again and it worked but thank you for your help :)

Comment: You are welcome :) I will make one note: when you FLOAT elements, they lose their "height" unless it is EXPLICITLY defined.

Comment: With no floating NOTHING overlaps, see [JSFiddle 4](http://jsfiddle.net/jJb77/4/)

Comment: WITH floating overlapping occurs with no height EXPLICITLY defined on the FLOATED element: [JSFiddle 3](http://jsfiddle.net/jJb77/4/)

Comment: Notice in [JSFiddle 5](http://jsfiddle.net/jJb77/5/) How the "lololol" text no appear BELOW the the image?